# How can I update my dynamic DNS under OpenWRT?

Tags: dns, openwrt, dyndns

I have an OpenWrt 10.03, and I need to update my dynamic DNS account (e.g., OpenDNS or DYNDNS) when my IP changes. How can I do this from the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at using [inadyn](http://www.inatech.eu/inadyn/), a client to update your DNS entries.

There is a page about it on the [DynDNS support site](http://www.dyndns.com/support/kb/using_inadyn_with_dyndns_services.html).

Alternatively, there is this line[1]:

```
curl -v -k -u user:password "https://members.dyndns.org/nic/update?hostname=&myip=$(curl -s http://checkip.dyndns.org | sed 's/[a-zA-Z/ :]//g')&wildcard=NOCHG&mx=NOCHG&backmx=NOCHG"
```

[1] Untested: from commandlinefu:
http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2492/update-dyndns.org-with-your-external-ip.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a recent version of openwrt and you have a package called luci-app-ddns where you can configure it on your web management console.
Also check the [OpenWrt documentation on this issue](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/ddns.client).